# 'If Then' loop with copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, copy-paste

I currently have a small bit of VBA that searches for criteria and does basic addition based on the conditions.  Works great and is the following:

```
Dim i As Long
i = 6
Do While Cells(i, "C").Value <> ""
If Cells(i, "C").Value = "9/12/2015" And Cells(i, "E").Value = "9/13/2015" Then
        Cells(i, "M").Value = Cells(i, "M").Value + 12
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
```

I now want to take it to the next level and instead of adding 12 to a column based on the criteria, do the following:

-select all the rows passing both conditions, and copy & paste their values from Sheet1 to Sheet2

I think the copy and paste part will be pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure about the best way to select different rows based on the result of the if...then statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long: i = 6
Dim r as Range

Do While Cells(i, "C").Value <> ""
  If Cells(i, "C").Value = "9/12/2015" And Cells(i, "E").Value = "9/13/2015" Then
    if r is nothing then
      set r = Cells(i, "M")
    else
      set r = application.union(r, Cells(i, "M"))
    end if
  End If

  i = i + 1
Loop

if not r is nothing then
  r.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the input GSerg--I've never used the application.union piece, what does that do? Also for the next bit of code, column M is irrelevant.  I simply just need it to select all the rows for which the 'If Then' statement is true, and copy & paste those rows into another worksheet.

Comment: @Willarci3 Then build up the range using `Cells(i, "M").EntireRow` instead of just `Cells(i, "M")`.